# Force crop/start with crop tool open

Tags: ios, swift, adobe, adobecreativesdk

With the Aviary SDK, it was possible to start the view controller with a tool open by default, and force the user to crop the photo before proceeding to close the editor.

I have scoured through the Adobe Creative SDK documentation to find the equivelent functions, but can find nothing.

Is it possible to do with the Adobe SDK?

(FYI: Adobe bought out the Aviary SDK)

Answer (score 0):

The Creative SDK Image Editor UI component doesn't currently support Quick Launch, the feature you are referring to.

However, it is possible to set the list of tools available to the user using the `setToolOrder:` method.

For example, if you only want to allow cropping, you can do this:

```
// Set the tool list to show Crop only.
[AdobeImageEditorCustomization setToolOrder:@[kAFCrop]];
```

For further information, [see the "Tool Order" section of the Image Editor UI guide on creativesdk.adobe.com](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/ios/#/articles/imageeditor/index.html#further-customization).